# Python mechanize doesn't click a button

Tags: python, mechanize, clientform

check the following script:

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
page = br.open('http://scottishladiespool.com/register.php')

br.select_form(nr = 5)

r = br.click(type = "submit", nr = 0)
print r.data
#prints username=&password1=&password2=&email=&user_hide_email=1&captcha_code=&user_msn=&user_yahoo=&user_web=&user_location=&user_month=&user_day=&user_year=&user_sig=
```

that is, it doesn't add the name=value pair of the submit button (register=Register). Why is this happening? ClientForm is working properly on other pages, but on this one it is not. I've tried setting the disabled and readonly attributes of submit control to True, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `disabled=disabled` attribute on the register button.  This prevents the user from clicking and presumably mechanize respects the `disabled` attribute as well.

You'll need to change the source code of that button. Enabling the control means completely removing the `disabled=disabled` text.

Comment: Weird, I've tried it before sending the question and it didn't work, now it does)

Comment: Heh - trust me we've all been there.